# error in generating owl alignment from rdf alignment using Align API

Tags: java, rdf, semantic-web, owl, apache-jena

I have done ontology matching on two ontologies and it's result is alignment.rdf. Now I want to generate owl file from alignment rdf using Align API library.

According to Align API documentation here is my code :

```
PrintWriter writer1 = null ;
    Alignment temp = null ;
    Alignment temp1 = null ;
    AlignmentParser aparser = new AlignmentParser();
    temp = aparser.parse( "file:Ontologies/final_alignment.rdf" );
    temp1 = ObjectAlignment.toObjectAlignment((URIAlignment)temp);
    File merged1 = new File( "Ontologies/final_alignment.owl");
    writer1 = new PrintWriter ( new FileWriter( merged1, false ), true );
    AlignmentVisitor renderer1 = new OWLAxiomsRendererVisitor( writer1 );
    temp1.render(renderer1);
    writer1.flush();
    writer1.close();
```

But I face this error in line`temp1 = ObjectAlignment.toObjectAlignment((URIAlignment)temp);` :

```
Error: Exception in thread "main" org.semanticweb.owl.align.AlignmentException: Arguments must be LoadedOntology or URI
```

how can I get rid of this error ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a follow-up to [1].

Like I answered "Note that for this purpose, the URI of the ontologies in the initial file must be dereferenceable."

More precisely, this means that from the URI in your file, Jena or the OWL API should be able to load the ontologies, and, since your trying to render them as OWL, these are OWLOntologies.

These may eventually be local URIs (starting with file://).

[1] [How to create Alignment Object using alignment API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39167732/how-to-create-alignment-object-using-alignment-api/42768429#42768429)